# Custom WordPress user permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have a little problem with my wordpress site. I need to change the user permalinks. The permalinks should contain data from wp_usermeta table.
I've made some functions and the links are changed, but when i access them it says: Page not found.
I'll buy you a beer if you can tell me what is wrong in my code.
Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse5742_request' );
function wpse5742_request( $query_vars )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( 'author_name', $query_vars ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $author_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE meta_key='nickname' AND meta_value = %s", $query_vars['author_name'] ) );
        $query_vars['author'] = $author_id;
        unset( $query_vars['author_name'] );    
    }
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter( 'author_link', 'wpse5742_author_link', 10, 3 );
function wpse5742_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename )
{
    $part1 = get_user_meta( $author_id, 'nickname', true );
    $part2 = get_user_meta( $author_id, '_themex_city', true );
    $part3 = get_user_meta( $author_id, '_themex_thesubject', true );
    $newlink  = $part1.'/'.$part2.'/'.$part3;

    if ( $newlink ) {
        $link = str_replace( $author_nicename, $newlink, $link );
    }
    return $link; 
}

add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'wpse5742_set_user_nicename_to_nickname', 10, 3 );
function wpse5742_set_user_nicename_to_nickname( &$errors, $update, &$user )
{
    if ( ! empty( $user->nickname ) ) {
        $user->user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user->nickname, $user->display_name );
    } }
```

The permalink I want to create is: **`example.com/username/city/occupation`**

Comment: the permalink format you have would match a parent/parent/child page rewrite pattern, how would that result in a request where the `author_name` query var would be set?

Comment: Are you telling me that this can't work?

Comment: it *could* work, but you'd be doing a lot of user meta queries on requests which are actually for pages. add `var_dump($query_vars);` to the top of your request filter to see what query vars are being set for those requests. not all of those requests will result in a user id, if it's actually for a parent/parent/child page. your other options are to add a rewrite rule to override any 3 level deep page requests (basically break the ability to load parent/parent/child pages), or look at how the wp no category base plugin works by adding a unique rule for each category (user, in your case).

Comment: Thank you for your time! Can you please help me to add that rewrite rule? I tried and it just won't go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with this question, and of a lot of questions like this, is the one pinted out by **@Milo** in comments: if you write a rewrite rule to handle you custom url, this goes in conflict with WordPress rules, e.g. if your urls are

```
htt://example.com/username/city/occupation
```

how WordPress can know if you are actually lookin for the page `occupation` child of page `city` granchild of page `username`?

Answer is **can't**, unless you do a query on database to see if the `username` part is a real username or not.

To simplify things like that I wrote a plugin called Clever Rules and in this answer I will use a technique I used for that plugin. This technique can't be used inside themes, but need to be used in plugins, so for this anwser I write a little plugin that uses 2 function taken from your code (just little bit optimized) and a small class that will do the *magic*.

### How it Works

1. I create a class that extends `WP` class.
2. Then I replace the global `$wp` variable (that normally contain an
   instance of `WP`) with an instance of my class. This one contain
   only a method: `parse_request` that override `WP` method, so when
   WordPress call `parse_request` the one my class is called instead
   of the core one.
3. In this method I check the current url, if it *seems* one we want to target
   I check the first part of the url and if it's a valid username set
   up the query vars otherwise let core `parse_request` run.

### Code

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: GM Custom Author Url WPSE Q#122829
 * Plugin URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122829/custom-wordpress-user-permalink
 * Author: G.M.
 * Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/g-m
 *
 */
class GMWPE extends WP {    
  function parse_request( $extra_query_vars = '' )
  {
    $home_path = trim( parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_PATH ), '/' );
    $full = str_replace( $home_path, '', add_query_arg( array() ) );
    $sane_array = explode( '?', $full );
    $sane = trim( $sane_array[0], '/\\' );
    $parts = array_filter( explode( '/', $sane ) );
    if ( count($parts) === 3 ) {
      $maybe_author = $parts[0];
      $user = get_user_by('slug', $maybe_author);
      if ( $user !== false ) {
        remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
        $this->query_vars = array( 'author' => $user->ID );
        return;
      }
    }
    parent::parse_request( $extra_query_vars = '' );
  } 
}

add_action( 'setup_theme', 'GMWPE_init', 9999 );
function GMWPE_init() {
  global $wp;
  if ( get_class( $wp ) === 'WP' ) $wp = new GMWPE();
}

add_filter( 'author_link', 'gmcau_author_link', 10, 3 );
function gmcau_author_link( $link, $author_id, $author_nicename )
{
  $part2 = get_user_meta( $author_id, '_themex_city', true );
  $part3 = get_user_meta( $author_id, '_themex_thesubject', true );
  if ( $part2 && $part3 ) {
    $newlink  = $author_nicename . '/' . $part2 . '/' . $part3;
    $link = home_url( $newlink );
  }
  return $link; 
}

add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'gmcau_set_user_nicename_to_nickname', 10, 3 );
function gmcau_set_user_nicename_to_nickname( &$errors, $update, &$user )
{
  if ( ! empty( $user->nickname ) ) {
   $user->user_nicename = sanitize_title( $user->nickname, $user->display_name );
  }
}
```

This is the only thing you need (you can remove the functions you posted). Save this code in a file, put it in your plugins folder and activate it form your dashboard.

---

PS: if you are interested in have a look on my plugin that use this technique to give a flexible urls handling you can find it [here](https://github.com/Giuseppe-Mazzapica/CleverRules).